# dxf-parser React library

Tags: reactjs, dxf

I'm currently developing a tool for my job, and I'm using the dxf-parser library in a React component. I'm not a programmer by trade, so I'm seeking some assistance with this project. The application's purpose is to:

Load a DXF File: The file contains data for a laser. I don't need to display the data; I just need to read it and extract information.
Extract Specific Information: From the DXF file, I need to determine the complete path length (which seems to be working) and accurately count the number of burnouts. However, there are issues with the burnout count.

For example, in tests with two different files, the path length is correctly read, but the burnout count is incorrect (i.e. it should be `3` and `1`, but it reads as `3` and `3`). Adjusting the threshold (possibly the distance between contours) hasn't resolved this issue, leading to inaccurate counts like `16+10`.

Perform Calculations: I plan to use the extracted data to calculate the laser burning time. I'm facing challenges with correctly reading the burnout count using the dxf-parser library. Does anyone have experience with this library and could offer assistance or tips to resolve this issue?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DXFParser from "dxf-parser";

const DXFLoader = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [pathLength, setPathLength] = useState(null);
  const [unconnectedContoursCount, setUnconnectedContoursCount] =
    useState(null);
  const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = useState(0);
  const [isDragOver, setIsDragOver] = useState(false);

  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      readFile(file);
    }
  };

  const handleDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsDragOver(false);
    const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if (file) {
      readFile(file);
    }
  };

  const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsDragOver(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setIsDragOver(false);
  };

  const parseDxf = (dxfText, isPath) => {
    const parser = new DXFParser();
    const parsedData = parser.parseSync(dxfText);

    let count = 0;

    const lines = parsedData.entities.filter(
      (entity) =>
        entity.type === "LINE" &&
        entity.vertices &&
        entity.vertices.length === 2
    );

    const distances = calculateDistancesBetweenEndPoints(lines);
    const threshold = isPath ? 0 : 150;
    const connectedLines = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (
        (isPath && distances[i] > threshold) ||
        (!isPath && distances[i] < threshold)
      ) {
        connectedLines.push(lines[i]);
      }
    }

    count = calculateCount(connectedLines, threshold);

    console.log(
      `Number of ${isPath ? "connected" : "unconnected"} contours in the file:`,
      count
    );

    // console.log(dxfText);

    return { lines: connectedLines, count };
  };

  const calculateDistancesBetweenEndPoints = (lines) => {
    return lines.map((line) => {
      const dx = line.vertices[1].x - line.vertices[0].x;
      const dy = line.vertices[1].y - line.vertices[0].y;
      return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    });
  };

  const calculateCount = (lines, threshold) => {
    const contours = lines.reduce((acc, line) => {
      const vertices = [
        { x: line.vertices[0].x, y: line.vertices[0].y },
        { x: line.vertices[1].x, y: line.vertices[1].y },
      ];

      let connected = false;

      // Procházíme všechny kontury a hledáme spojení s aktuální čarou
      for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        const contour = acc[i];

        // Procházíme všechny body v kontuře a hledáme spojení s aktuální čarou
        for (let j = 0; j < contour.length - 1; j++) {
          const lastVertex = contour[j];
          const firstVertex = vertices[0];

          const dx = lastVertex.x - firstVertex.x;
          const dy = lastVertex.y - firstVertex.y;
          const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

          if (distance < threshold) {
            // Spojujeme pouze, pokud čára není součástí kontury
            if (
              contour.indexOf(vertices[1]) === -1 &&
              contour.indexOf(vertices[0]) === -1
            ) {
              contour.push(vertices[1]);
            }
            connected = true;
            break; // Pokud jsme našli spojení, nemusíme procházet další body v kontuře
          }
        }

        if (connected) {
          break; // Pokud jsme našli spojení, nemusíme procházet další kontury
        }
      }

      if (!connected) {
        acc.push([...vertices]);
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);

    return contours.length;
  };

  const calculatePathLength = (parsedDxf) => {
    const pathLength = parsedDxf.lines.reduce((totalLength, line) => {
      const dx = line.vertices[1].x - line.vertices[0].x;
      const dy = line.vertices[1].y - line.vertices[0].y;
      const segmentLength = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return totalLength + segmentLength;
    }, 0);

    setPathLength(pathLength);
    return pathLength;
  };

  const readFile = (file) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const dxfText = e.target.result;

      try {
        const parsedDxfPath = parseDxf(dxfText, true);
        const parsedDxfUnconnected = parseDxf(dxfText, false);
        const calculatedPathLength = calculatePathLength(parsedDxfPath);

        setPathLength(calculatedPathLength);
        setUnconnectedContoursCount(parsedDxfUnconnected.count);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        setError(new Error("Chyba při zpracování DXF souboru."));
      }

      setLoading(false);
      setProgressValue(0);
    };

    reader.onerror = (e) => {
      setError(new Error("Chyba při čtení souboru."));
      setLoading(false);
      setProgressValue(0);
    };

    reader.onprogress = (e) => {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const percentLoaded = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        setProgressValue(percentLoaded);
      }
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onDrop={handleDrop}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
        style={{
          border: isDragOver ? "2px dashed #39a2db" : "2px dashed #ccc",
          padding: "20px",
          textAlign: "center",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
      >
        <p>Přetáhněte nebo vyberte DXF soubor:</p>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept=".dxf"
          onChange={handleFileUpload}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="fileInput"
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="fileInput"
          style={{
            cursor: "pointer",
            padding: "10px",
            border: "1px solid #ccc",
            borderRadius: "2rem", // Zakulacené rohy
            backgroundColor: "#39a2db", // Barva tlačítka
            color: "#fff", // Barva textu tlačítka
            display: "inline-block", // Tlačítko je nyní pod textem
          }}
        >
          Vybrat soubor
        </label>
      </div>

      {loading && (
        <div>
          <p>Načítání...</p>
          <progress max="100" value={progressValue} />
        </div>
      )}

      {error && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Chyba: {error.message}</p>}

      {!loading && pathLength !== null && unconnectedContoursCount !== null && (
        <div>
          <p>Celková řezná dráha: (this means cutting path lenght) {pathLength}</p>
          <p>Počet propalů: (this means number of burnouts) {unconnectedContoursCount}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DXFLoader;
```